# Convert a DataFrame to a specific dictionary format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert this dataframe to a specific dictionary format:

```
lake = pd.DataFrame({'area': [10, 10, 30, 40],  'count': [7, 5, 2, 3]})
```

```
In [41]: lake                                                                                                             
Out[41]: 
     area  count
0      10      7
1      10      5
2      30      2
3      40      3

In [42]:   `
```

Is there a way to get this:

```
{'10': [7,5], '30': 2, '40': 3}
```

without using the `iterrows` on the `df`

Comment: You can do this: `dict(lake.groupby('area')['count'].apply(list))`

Comment: In this case I would suggest using a pandas `Series` instead of a `DataFrame`. `lake = pd.Series([7, 5, 2, 3], index = [10, 10, 30, 40],  name='count') ` and then simply `lake.to_dict()`.